# How is this nested loop being evaluated?

Tags: python, loops, nested

## (Python3) How are the values 0,6,18,36 calculated?

```
stop = 20
result = 0

# Start nested loop
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(4):
        result += a * b
    print(result)
    if result > stop:
        break
```

> ---OUTPUT---
> 0
> 6
> 18
> 36

Comment: Use an IDE such as Spyder and step in line by line and observe each variable as it changes.

Comment: You could add a print right before `result += a * b` - `print('next calculation:', result, a, b)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's not clear what exactly you need help with. Do you know how the math works? Do you know how the loops work?

Comment: If it helps your understanding, you can replace the inner loop with `result += a * sum(range(1, 4))`, but then `sum(range(1, 4))` is a fixed value, 6, so: `result += a * 6`

Comment: Why closed? I see a question, a script, output. Its got all the parts.

Answer (score 1):

First a loop where a equals zero, result keeps being incremented by 0 times 1, then times 2...times 4 essentially 0.

Second loop, a equals 1 and result is being incremented by 1 times 0, times 1, times 2 and times 3. Total 6.

Third loop result incremented by 2 times 0 then times 1...times 3. Total increment is 12 in addition to 6 makes 18.

Last loop, same thing with 3. result is incremented by a total of 18 and becomes 36. At which point, it exits the loop after printing 36 because it is greater than stop = 20.

Answer (score 0):

Let python tell you

```
stop = 20
result = 0
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(4):
        print(f'next calc: {result} += {a} * {b}')
        result += a * b
        print(f'       ==> {result}')
    print(result)
    if result > stop:
        break
```

Output

```
next calc: 0 += 0 * 0
       ==> 0
next calc: 0 += 0 * 1
       ==> 0
next calc: 0 += 0 * 2
       ==> 0
next calc: 0 += 0 * 3
       ==> 0
0
next calc: 0 += 1 * 0
       ==> 0
next calc: 0 += 1 * 1
       ==> 1
next calc: 1 += 1 * 2
       ==> 3
next calc: 3 += 1 * 3
       ==> 6
6
next calc: 6 += 2 * 0
       ==> 6
next calc: 6 += 2 * 1
       ==> 8
next calc: 8 += 2 * 2
       ==> 12
next calc: 12 += 2 * 3
       ==> 18
18
next calc: 18 += 3 * 0
       ==> 18
next calc: 18 += 3 * 1
       ==> 21
next calc: 21 += 3 * 2
       ==> 27
next calc: 27 += 3 * 3
       ==> 36
36
```